# input read from nextLine is not equal to String value

Tags: java, string

I got this code:

```
    System.out.println("Enter the brand and cash value");

    String brand = keyboard.nextLine();

    long cash = keyboard.nextDouble();
    String buffer = keyboard.nextLine();
```

but even though I enter the exact String value I am trying to compare to, it fails to recognize they are the same. Strangely when I enter this:

`compare[0] = new Car ("BMW", 12.00);`

instead of this:

`compare[0] = new Car (brand, 12.00);`

it works

I also use equals:

```
public boolean equals(Car other)
{
    if (other == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(this.brand == other.brand && this.cash == other.cash)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using .equals() method for checking equality ? == would not work here

Comment: Right before you do the comparison, print out both Strings you are comparing.  This should help you see if there are any differences.  Also, don't use '==' to compare Strings (as already stated).

Comment: i use equals i redefined it

Comment: @GladstoneAsder: No, you're using `==` *within* `equals`...

Comment: == only works with strings?

Comment: ah i changed == to equals and it works now. i don't understand why it worked the last time i used it with ==... uhh isn't == supposed to work with strings? brand is a string object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using `==` to test String equality, and `"BMW"` is a String literal, which is interned in a pool whereas `brand` isn't. In other words, if you have:

```
String s1 = "BMW";
String s2 = "BMW";
String s3 = getString(); //receives "BMW" from the scanner
```

`s1 == s2` is true
`s1 == s3` is false
`s2 == s3` is false
`s1.equals(s2)` is true
`s1.equals(s3)` is true
`s2.equals(s3)` is true

Bottom line: you should use `equals` to compare strings.

You can read more about it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java).

**EDIT**

In the code of your `equals` method you need to change

```
if(this.brand == other.brand && this.cash == other.cash)
```

to this:

```
if(this.brand.equals(other.brand) && this.cash == other.cash)
```

Also note there are a few other issues with your `equals` - in particular, it does not override equals: it should be `public boolean equals(Object o)`

**EDIT 2**

You could implement your equals method like this for example (it assumes that brand can't be null - if it is not the case you need to handle that specific case too)

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj == null || getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }

    final Car other = (Car) obj;
    return (this.cash == other.cash && this.brand.equals(other.brand));
}
```

Note that you should also override the `hashcode` method.

Comment: i use equals() that's probably not the problem

Comment: @GladstoneAsder I understand that you overrode `equals` in your Book class. Can you show that code? I would imagine that within the `equals` method, you compare the brands with `if (this.brand == other.brand) {}`.

Comment: when i change car to object it gives me the following errors: cannot find symbols and are you sure that's the error? it worked in my earlier program.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use

`this.brand.equals(other.brand)`

in your `if` clause instead of

```
this.brand == other.brand
```

The `==` is used to check the reference of String and its value..

In this case your values are same but not the reference.

So you need to use `equals` cause it is used to check values only.
and thats what you want to do I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use `java.lang.Object`'s equal method as I've shown below

```
public boolean equals(Car other)
{
    if (other == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if(this.brand.equals(other.brand) && this.cash.equals(other.cash))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @vels4j It depends if cash is a `double` or a `Double`. It seems to be a `double` though in which case the `equals` thingy won't compile indeed.